# How to select all text boxes with a particular text in Jquery

Tags: jquery

If I do this:

```
$("[value='xxx']")
```

It selects textboxes that were sent from the webserver with a `value=xxx`.

It won't select the textboxes that were set `xxx` by the user at the client side.

On a dropdown selection, if the text matches, I want to hide those textboxes. How do I do this?

Comment: You could probably use `$.on()` to detect the change.

Comment: Do you want to get the text from text input fields or from HTML textarea tags?

Comment: So when the user chooses an option in a `<select>`, you want to hide `<input type="text">` elements whose value is equal to the value of the option chosen in the `<select>`, right? Is there some reason you have to use an attribute selector, or can you listen for `change` on the `<select>` and then use a `filter()` call as indicated by @ahren?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input, textarea").filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() == 'XXX';  
}).hide();
```

Use the `.filter()` function.

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/filter

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pmuuM/ (try clicking the button before and after changing the value to XXX)

Or (since the question updated):

```
$('input, textarea').on('change', function(){
    if(this.value == 'XXX') $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Is `$.filter()` dynamic *after* page load? That's the problem. I'm thinking `$.on()` or some other delegate is necessary here.

Comment: Modified the question ...sorry:(

Comment: Honestly, `$.click()` and `$.submit()` occur with different dependencies. It's not that easy.